# cannot change the date format in mysql table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to change the date format in my database table Time column and I sued this code but didn't effected!

I tried it with code but didn't work! the part of date edit is

```
$date = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(time, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i') FROM climate";
```

and this is my full code:

```
 $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

 // Check connection

 if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }

   echo "Connected successfully";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO climate (temp, hum, time) VALUES ('$temp', 
  '$hum', 
  '$time')";
   $date = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(time, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i') FROM climate";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $date)) {
// output data of each row
    echo "OK";

 } else {
 echo "0 results";
 }
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
 } else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
 }
```

Comment: The format will always be `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` in the database. You need to format it when you select it.

Comment: Mind the SQL injections

Comment: So my way is wrong! how can change it? Thanks

Comment: It's not at all clear what we are trying to achieve here. The `DATE_FORMAT` function returns a string value. Executing a `SELECT` statement that includes the `DATE_FORMAT` function in an expression in the select list doesn't change anything in the database. `DATE`,`DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP`, `TIME` datatypes each have default format(s) that MySQL expects/interprets. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html  to supply a value in some other format, we can use a function like `STR_TO_DATE`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: Apart from that, I guess we can just say "Thanks for the status report." Because it doesn't appear that there was an actual *question* asked. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format that is stored in any date-type column in MySQL will be of the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. This cannot be changed - but it does not matter, as you can format it any way you like when selecting the values - either in PHP after retrieving it, or by using `DATE_FORMAT()` in the `SELECT` statement.

You should also be using prepared statements instead of injecting values directly into the query.

These `SELECT` statements will only select one row - but it is just to show the principle of formatting *after* the values have been inserted (as they will, as previously stated, always have the same format in the table).

Keep in mind that when you send data to SQL, it should be of an un-ambigious format such as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, you may risk confusing dates otherwise (example, is `2/1/2019` the first of February, or second of January?).

```php
// Inserting a new row
$sql = "INSERT INTO climate (temp, hum, time) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $temp, $hum, $time);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

// Fetch a row and format the time in SQL
$sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(time, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i') FROM climate";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($time_formatted);
$stmt->fetch();
echo $time_formatted;
$stmt->close();
```

Alternatively, you can format it in PHP after fetching it

```php
$sql = "SELECT time FROM climate";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($time_formatted);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
$date = new DateTime($time_formatted);
echo $date->format("m/d/Y H:i");
```

Mind you that this has no error-handling and always assumes that everything will always work, you might want to consider adding some proper error-handling.

Comment: I tried it but didn't make any change in time format in the table

Comment: Like I said, *it will not change in the table*. It's not needed either. You have to format it when you select it. Read the description along with the answer.

Comment: yes I understand it now thank you very much :) I am beginner with PHP and learning. :)